# php.ini reset him self ioncube install

Tags: php, centos6, ioncube

ihave problem with php.ini
im install ioncube and add the line

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so
```

im restart the server and its work,
and after couple of minutes the php.ini file back to his orginal.

im using
CentOS6
ISPManager Pro.

thanks.

Comment: I'd guess something in ISPManager Pro manages that file. Ask their support or consult their documentation.

Comment: i ask them its not from the panel any help?